# Ideal way to define configuration in pom.xml which is not related to any plugin

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

Our Java application has one Integration Test module which only has integration tests which runs in a GCP vm. While running these tests in gcp vm, we use Jacoco(*in GCP vm in server mode*) to calculate Integrated Test code coverage for whole repo. Now we want to specify exlcusion inclusion Jacoco configuration like we do in Jacoco-maven-plugin for UTs. For Unit Tests we are already specifying configuration in each module under Jacoco-maven-plugin. For Integrated Tests, we want to specify the configuration of all modules in Integration Test module in a single xml. These configs are then read by GCP vm Jacoco Agent to get list of all included excluded classes and generate coverage. Basically these configs will not be used by java project itself but will be by pipeline.

I was thinking of putting configuration in `properties` section of pom.xml of IT module, so that java code can read it but it seems properties are simple key value pair and cant accept xml nodes. What would be ideal way to store these configs?  This is how much config will look like -

```
<it>
            <servicemodule1>
                <jacocoincludes>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                </jacocoincludes>
                <jacocoexcludes>
                    <exclude>com/example/**</exclude>
                </jacocoexcludes>
            </servicemodule1>
            <servicemodule2>
                <jacocoincludes>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                </jacocoincludes>
                <jacocoexcludes>
                    <exclude>com/example/**</exclude>
                </jacocoexcludes>
            </servicemodule2>
            <servicemodule3>
                <jacocoincludes>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                </jacocoincludes>
                <jacocoexcludes>
                    <exclude>com/example/**</exclude>
                </jacocoexcludes>
            </servicemodule3>
        </it>
```

Last option would be to simple create a xml in resources folder but wanted to check if it can be present in pom.xml and pom allows storing config which is not related to any maven plugin.